# Python child class with more methods

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a quick question about how to deal with an inheritance problem.

Let's say we have a vehicle object

```
class vehicle(object):

    __init__(registration):
         registration = self.registration

    get_details():
         return "This is a vehicle"
```

And then a truck that inherits from vehicle

```
class truck(vehicle):

      get_details():
         return "This is a truck"
```

We have lots of classes all with the same methods and properties e.g. bus, car, train. However, we also have an airplane which inherits from vehicle but only airplane has a new method called  `required_takeoff_distance()`

Is it OK to only have it in the airplane class or should you also add it to the vehicle class with a default of `raise NotImplementedError()`?

Comment: It is way better to have the required_takeoff_distance only in the airplane class since as you point it, this method only make sense for airplane. Adding the method to the base class would break the SOLID principles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly OK for a child class to define more methods than are available on the parent class. Indeed, this is the usual reason for creating a child class in the first place.

Do not add a method with `raise NotImplementedError` onto the parent class unless you're trying to define an interface / [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class). This is almost never needed in Python, so if you're not sure what it means you can safely forget about it.

Comment: I agree with _"if you're not sure what it means you can safely forget about it."_, but I dont with _"This is almost never needed in Python"_. That radically depends on what you use Python for. I have been recently dedicating a lot of time to building some frameworks and I use it a lot.